# How can I Redirect to controller with variable or data or value with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

How to Redirect to controller with variable/data/value with JavaScript? 
To redirect to another page with JavaScript I usually use *window.location.href= site_url('controller_name')*.

If I want to redirect with array value that I give a name as $data: How to write it?

Thank you for your attention. I hope you can help me.

Comment: What have you tried? It depends on how you implement your controller's route that you're redirecting to. Typically, query string is used. It's hard to say without looking at some samples of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 window.location.href = "controllerName?data=" + data;
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP -**

```
<?php 
    $arr = array("name"=>"xyz","email"=>"email@xyz.com");
    $paramters = http_build_query($arr);

    $redirect_url = base_url().'ControllerName/MethodName?data='.$paramters;
?>
```

**JavaScript -**

Now only pass this variable where ever you redirect;

```
<script>

    window.location.href = "<?php echo $redirect_url ?>";

</script>
```

P.S - Both must be on the same page.